# Изменить метод в зависимости от cookies

Tags: javascript, typescript

Необходимо, чтобы метод возвращал `{ device_id: device_id }` если в cookies есть строка `device_id`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше реализовать в данном случае?

```js
import { UAParser } from 'ua-parser-js';

export interface IDevice {
  user_agent: string;
  browser_name?: string;
  browser_version?: string;
  device_type?: string;
  device_vendor?: string;
  os_name?: string;
  os_version?: string;
  device_id?: number;
}

export class Device {
  public user_agent: string;
  public browser_name?: string; 
  public os_name?: string;
  public device_type?: string;
  public device_id?: number;


  constructor(user_agent: string) {
    this.user_agent = user_agent;
  }

  detect(): IDevice | null{

    var parser = new UAParser();
  
    this.browser_name = parser.setUA(this.user_agent).getBrowser().name;
    this.os_name = parser.setUA(this.user_agent).getOS().name;
    this.device_type = parser.setUA(this.user_agent).getDevice().type;
    
    return {
      user_agent: this.user_agent,
      browser_name: this.browser_name,
      os_name: this.os_name,
      device_type: this.device_type
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с cookie в Angular вы можете использовать [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service)

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ CookieService ],
})
```

**device.component.ts**

```
import { UAParser } from 'ua-parser-js';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

constructor(user_agent: string, cookieService: CookieService) {
  ...
}

detect() {
  ...
  this.device_id = this.cookieService.get('device_id') || null;
}

setDeviceId(device_id: string): void {
  this.cookieService.set('device_id', device_id);
}

checkDeviceId(): boolean {
  this.cookieService.check('device_id');
}
```